# What does the third eye of the Sage of the Six Paths do?

Tags: naruto

The Sage of the Six Paths had **Rinnegan** in both in his eyes. He also awakened a third eye on his forehead.

[image]

Is that a **Sharingan** of some kind?

What powers does that third eye grant it's wielder?

Comment: Naruto has a pretty big wikia, have you tried looking there?

Comment: It has never been mentioned in the manga I believe. Anything else is considered as conjecture. Is everything in the wiki can be considered as canon?

Comment: It doesn't seem like an eye. The third eye that Kaguya has is more pronounced with distinct features. This is more like a symbol. More like the clan symbols on forehead protectors. Wikia also doesn't classify it as an eye

Comment: It could be another evolution of the sharing an since he awakend it with his mangekyo

Answer (score 6):

From the Wiki

> After awakening his Rinnegan, he also manifested a red circle marking with two ripples patterns in the centre of his forehead, seemingly a byproduct of his ultimate dōjutsu manifested alongside his senjutsu training.

It references episode 426 of Naruto Shippuden and suggests it wasn't a true eye but rather a marking. There's no way to be sure if it gave him any special powers, but all

> abilities he exhibited were in line with what we know was possible via his Rinnegan / Mangekyo / Senjutsu abilities so it doesn't seem to have given him anything.

Additionally it's flat and lacks the depth that Kaguya's third eye had, also suggesting it was simply a marking. The best theory I can come up with is that it was an incomplete manifestation of Kaguya's third eye.

Comment: This the really good. I have always wondered about it. You are right, it lacks the depth to be an eye.

Comment: However, is it true that rinnegan also had the power to transport between dimensions? If not then I had this theory that , the marking on his forehead was responsible for that.

Comment: My other theory was, since ninjas who are trained in sage mode often have markings in them (hashirama markings under his eyes ) may be because of that, the sage got the marking in his eyes permanently due to his sage powers. Again, this is a speculation.

Comment: While the Senjutsu theory is plausible, the Rinnegan doesn't possess the ability to teleport between dimensions, at least not innately, as according to the wiki it's an ability of  Kaguya's Rinne-sharigan http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amenominaka , further supported by the fact that Hagoromo had the Kage assist him in using a summoning technique to bring team 7 back after sealing Kaguya http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hagoromo ((in the Part II part of his Bio)) instead of simply bringing them himself

Answer (score 2):

It could signal the use of his sage of six paths sage mode. Every user of sage mode has always had some sort of marking when using their own form of sage mode. This could signal his. 6 paths sage power, like naruto's commas and eyes and hashiramas markings.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that marking is the Mangekyo Sharingan. When Hagoromo and Hamura (both sons of Kaguya Otsutsuki) fight Kaguya, Hagoromo has to kill his brother for he was under the control of Kaguya. But thanks to Gamamaru (presently the great toad sage), Hamura was saved by sage power.

Immediately after this incident, Hagoromo awakens his Rinnegan and also his Mangekyo Sharingan. He also thanks his mother (Kaguya) for she was only responsible for the awakening of his Rinnegan and Mangekyo Sharingan.

Comment: You're going to want to add sources to this.

Answer (score 1):

It is the Mangekyo Sharingan. When Hagoromo "kills" Hamura and gains his Rinnegan, he also gains the "third eye." It doesn't really look like an eye, but more of a marking representing the Mangekyo Sharingan. When Sasuke gains his Rinnegan, his Rinnegan manifest in his left Mangekyo Sharingan eye. In Sasuke's Rinnegan, there is tomoe which shows when he is at full power and that there used to be a sharingan in that eye. It also shows that he still has the power of his left Mangekyo Sharingan. Though an issue with this hypothesis is that Madara did not have tomoe in his Rinnegan and did not get the Rinne Sharingan till late in the series. And I'm pretty sure he still had the power of his Sharingan, even when both his eyes were Rinnegan.

In all, the red mark probably represents the Mangekyo Sharingan in order to show that Hagaromo has both the power of the Sharingan and the Rinnegan.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things it does. Number 1 it has the Chakra that worth ten tails which is Canon and if that's not enough proof madra absorbs ten tails then he gets rinnesharrigan. The other thing it does it does is that it does the infinite tsukuyomi. The last thing it does it typically opens portal for transportation and sometimes in rare instances like kaguya has unique abilities like bringing people to dimension instantly or going through half the dimension like an open door.